# Undefined reference to 'fff' at linker

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, undefined-reference, fake-function-framework

I'm getting the following linker error when I build a GoogleTest executable (with CMake) that uses FFF (Fake Function Framework):

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/module_test.dir/objects.a(module_tes
ts.cpp.obj):module_tests.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.fff[.refptr.fff]+0x0): undefined reference to `fff'
```

The project has a source file:

## module_tests.cpp:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>


extern "C" {
#include "fff.h"
FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(uint16_t, MODULEA_getSampleValue);
}

extern "C" {
#include "module_b.h"
}

// Tests written here
```

Then the "module_b.h" itself #includes "module_a.h". I don't understand what is causing the undefined reference error. I'm building the project using Cmake, which I may have also configured incorrectly. The CMakeLists.txt for the tests is:

## CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(module_test
    src/module_tests.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(module_test
    PRIVATE
        gtest_main
        MODULE_A
        MODULE_B
    )

target_include_directories(module_test
    PUBLIC
        ../inc
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(module_test)
```

What do I have configured incorrectly here that would cause this undefined reference error?

Comment: Undefined reference comes from linking, not compiling. You didn't link the object file that defines `fff`.

Comment: What does your entire `CMakeLists.txt` look like?   What does `fff.h` look like?  Please show us a [mre]

Comment: @DrewDormann It is a MRE, given that `fff.h` is from a library that is both tagged and clearly mentioned in question. The only thing to improve is that GTest is not necessary to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the globals needed by FFF. If you look at the github page, or any of the tests included with FFF, you'll find that there is the line

```
DEFINE_FFF_GLOBALS;
```

whose expansion includes the definition of `fff` needed.

```
fff_globals_t fff;
```

This is taken literally from `README.md`. I don't see how you can possibly miss it.

> Here's how you would define a fake function for this in your test
> suite:
>
> ```
> // test.c(pp)
>
> #include "fff.h"
> DEFINE_FFF_GLOBALS;
> FAKE_VOID_FUNC(DISPLAY_init);
> ```

Comment: It's unclear that you have to call this macro and do so exactly once in entire program. It's only used this once in readme, without any explanation whatsoever. If I hadn't read source code, I wouldn't guess either.

Comment: OK, I thought it was obvious, but maybe you are right, the documentation can be improved.

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected now. As @Yksisarvinen mentioned, I missed this because I was originally operating off of the example shown later in the documentation, under the "How do I reuse a fake across multiple test-suites" section, which does not include this definition. I later attempted to simplify by moving from separate declare/defines to the FAKE_VOID_FUNC which does both. Appreciate the help!